# MySQL query php conditional

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a sql query, but I would like to make sure if someone doesn't upload an avatar (avatar_filename), it will display an alternative avatar (/images/avatars/default.jpg).

I've been looking at if conditionals on this website and tried to used them without success.

This is my working query for the moment:

```
$query =   "SELECT exp_forum_topics.last_post_author_id, exp_forum_topics.title, exp_forum_topics.topic_id, exp_forum_topics.last_post_date, exp_members.member_id, exp_members.screen_name, exp_members.avatar_filename ".
                        "FROM exp_forum_topics, exp_members ".
                        "WHERE exp_forum_topics.last_post_author_id = exp_members.member_id ".
                        "ORDER BY exp_forum_topics.last_post_date DESC ".
                        "LIMIT 4";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<img src="/images/avatars/';
    echo $row['avatar_filename'];
    echo '" />';

    echo "<h3><a href='/forum/viewthread/";
    echo $row['topic_id'];
    echo "'>";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "</a></h3>";

    echo "<p>by <a href='/forum/members/";
    echo $row['last_post_author_id'];
    echo "'>";
    echo $row['screen_name'];
    echo "</a></p>";
 }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the returned value is empty and set your default image as follows:

```
if (!empty($row['avatar_filename'])) {
  echo '<img src="/images/avatars/';
  echo $row['avatar_filename'];
  echo '" />';
} else {
  echo '<img src="/images/avatars/default.jpg" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks vinodadhikary, exactly what I needed. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered setting the field (column) in the table with a default value? e.g. DEFAULT='my-image.jpg' or something similar?

Comment: +1 This is what I would do. Simply define a default value in the SQL schema for that column.

Answer (score 1):

Define default in column database.

Or...

```
if (!isset($row['avatar_filename']) {
    echo 'default_avatar.png';
} else {
    echo $row['avatar_filename'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this in the SQL

in the select list, just replace this:

```
 exp_members.avatar_filename
```

with something like:

```
 COALESCE(NULLIF(exp_members.avatar_filename,''),'default.jpg') 
   AS avatar_filename
```

That's equivalent to:

```
 CASE WHEN exp_members.avatar_filename <> ''
      THEN exp_members.avatar_filename
      ELSE 'default.jpg'
 END AS avatar_filename
```

This essentially emulates the column having a default value of `'default.jpg'`, by returning that value whenever the column is `NULL` or is equal to the empty string `''`.